# Why does styling a button's border affect its background color on hover and click?

Tags: html, css, button

In Chrome and other browsers, an unstyled button's background color will get slightly darker than the default color on hover, and slightly lighter than the default color while the button is pressed.

However, if the style of the button's border is changed (for example, by applying a border radius), the background color no longer changes on hover or while the button is pressed. Why is that?

```css
button { padding: 1ch 2ch; }
.border-radius { border-radius: 1rem; }
```

```html
<button type="button">Border Unstyled</button>
<button class="border-radius" type="button">Border Radius Applied</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "click effects"?

Comment: I removed a border and border-radius from the features, when you add it then the button is unable to click

Comment: check now, please

Comment: What _specifically_ (visually or otherwise) are you expecting to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: I added this question just due to curiosity, why button have no 'click' effect after adding border/border-radius? I want to addEventListener to change the bacgournd color

Comment: What _specific_ effect are you expecting it to have? Are you expecting the border to change color when you click it? the background? What specific effect?? You must articulate how this is different than your expectations. We don't know what you mean by "click effect".

Comment: I meant the background color is slightly lighter when you click on the button

Comment: I have overhauled the question for clarity and voted to reopen. Note that I've changed the code example to illustrate the difference between a button with border styles and a button without border styles, and I've removed extraneous code unrelated to reproducing the effect. I've also specifically described the expectations and question. It's important to put a lot of effort into making questions concise, specific, and clear.

Comment: Depends on the platform re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button